# Expresión regular que valide que le estoy pasando un número o un vacío

Tags: javascript, regex

Necesito poder pasar solamente números o vacíos (`null`).

Esta expresión solo me deja pasar números:

```
let onlyNumbers = /^[0-9]*$/;
```

Comment: a que te refieres con "o vacios (null)"? Tu valor es un string? esperas que alguien pase "null" (como string) y sea valido? o esperas que sea un string con numeros o el valor null de javascript? esperas que un string vacio sea valido o no? podrias completar tu código de como usas la expresion?

Comment: No olvides mostrar ejemplos de uso (aunque tu caso sea muy básico).

Comment: ¿Con null te refieres a espacios en blanco? Me parece un poco raro tener que validar null. Gracias

Comment: ¿Y si verificás si es null por separado? `if texto === null || onlyNumbers.test(texto) {` ... ¿Eso estás buscando? Porque no se entiende la pregunta

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con esta expresión regular:

var patronNumerosEspacios = new RegExp(/^[0-9\s]*$/g);

\s indica espacios en blanco. Te envio esta solución porque me parece raro validar si es null con expresiones regulares.
Un saludo

Comment: Suena a que más bien quiso decir "o que tenga solo números, o que la cadena sea vacía". Tu expresión regular también es válida cuando se ingresa "9 9 9 9" por ejemplo. Esperemos a ver si edita la pregunta especificando su planteamiento.